# Accidentally added a receiving monero address, How do i delete?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I stupidly Accidentally added a receiving monero address by pasting an address into the 1 part of the receiving page on monero wallet under my primary receiving address.

I cannot find a way to undo or delete this? Can anyone help

Comment: Addresses in Monero are deterministic. You can't select a custom one. So if you can change the value of a text widget showing your receiving address, it's only a cosmetic thing and should be back to normal if you restart the GUI.